# DAX IF function syntax error- creating a conditional column

Tags: excel, dax, powerquery, powerpivot

I've got a csv with 900,000 rows.
42 of them are duplicates.
PQ's Remove Duplicates function removes rows that aren't true dupes.

I can successfully filter for these 42 rows in the PQ Editor, but I can't figure out how to remove them (can't select more than one).

The dupes are ones that have a null birthdate and 7/17/1989 registration date. Both of those columns are date format.

I'm trying to instead add a conditional column with this formula: =IF(AND(ISBLANK[Voters_BirthDate]), [Voters_OfficialRegDate]= "7/17/1989")), "Y", " ")

but I'm getting a syntax error "The syntax for ',' is incorrect."
It's referring to the comma before "Y", but that comma should be there, right?

Comment: I think you're missing an open-parentheses for ISBLANK. Annnd ... you have four ) but only two (. So you're missing another (.

Answer (score 1):

Urgh, nested formulas. I *think* this is right:

```
=IF(AND(ISBLANK([Voters_BirthDate]), ([Voters_OfficialRegDate]= "7/17/1989")), "Y", " ")
```

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I was just missing an open parenthesis after ISBLANK